# Specifying a domain and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I'm making a graph with `pgfplots` with a specific domain, but the graph's domain (both x and y) are not changing. I'm reading through the pgfplots manual and I think I'm doing the right thing except that it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=$\mathrm{\frac{1}{[S]}}$,ylabel=$\mathrm{\frac{1}{\textit{V}_0}}$]
  \addplot+[scatter,domain=-100:10000,y domain=-0.05:0.05] coordinates {
    (10000, 0.030)
    (5000, 0.02)
    (2000, 0.014)
    (1000, 0.012)
    (500,  0.0110)
    (200,  0.0104)
    (100,  0.0102)
    (50,   0.010)
    (20,   0.01)
    (10,   0.01)
    (5,    0.01) 
  };

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please reduce your example to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: It's not minimal yet. There are still packages that don't seem to be related to your problems. Have a look at the link I provided.

Comment: The only packages I have are `lmodern`, `tikz`, and `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Halime: I was just about to post an answer to your new question regarding the regression line. Have you figured out how to use the regression parameters yourself?

Comment: @Jake: I realized that I already had the equation for the line of best fit, so I'd just plot the points for the x-intercept and an additional point. However, does pgfplots have a way of doing it instead of me computing it manually?

Comment: @Jake: Alright I made the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The manual (p. 34 for version 1.5) says

> The `domain` keys are only relevant for `gnuplot` and `plot expression`. In
>   case you’d like to plot only a subset of other coordinate input
>   routines, consider using the coordinate filter `restrict x to domain`.

That restricts the domain of the co-ordinates, but does  not alter the axes you get (it effectively moves the data points). I think you just want the `xmax`, `xmin`, `ymax` and `ymin` keys, which apply to the axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [xlabel=$\mathrm{\frac{1}{[S]}}$,ylabel=$\mathrm{\frac{1}{\textit{V}_0}}$,
    xmin=-100,xmax=10000,ymin=-0.05,ymax=0.05]
  \addplot+[scatter] coordinates {
    (10000, 0.030)
    (5000, 0.02)
    (2000, 0.014)
    (1000, 0.012)
    (500,  0.0110)
    (200,  0.0104)
    (100,  0.0102)
    (50,   0.010)
    (20,   0.01)
    (10,   0.01)
    (5,    0.01) 
  };

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! Also, what page of the manual are you citing? I'd just like to read more on that for my own reference.